# How to remove unexpected padding of Labels in .NET MAUI?

Tags: maui

I made a login page with 2 Labels and Entries and 1 Button in my .NET MAUI project, and I ran the project on Windows Machine and on my Pixel 3a using wireless debugging (got same result on Pixel 7a).
It looks very good on Windows Machine, but on Android, it looks like labels have unnatural padding.

**Here is a screenshot on Windows Machine:**
[Screenshot on Windows Machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixg7y.png)

**On Android:**
[Screenshot on Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWWhS.png)

How do I remove them on Android?

**Login Page XAML:**

```
<ScrollView>
    <ScrollView.Content>
        <VerticalStackLayout Padding="40,0" VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Label Style="{StaticResource LoginFormLabel}"
                   Text="User Name"
                   Margin="0,30,0,0"
                   Padding="0"
                   ></Label>


            <Entry Placeholder="Your user name..."
                   Style="{StaticResource LoginFormEntry}"
                   Margin="0"
                   Text="{Binding UserName}"></Entry>

            <Label Style="{StaticResource LoginFormLabel}"
                   Text="Password"
                   Margin="0,30,0,0"
                   ></Label>



            <Entry Placeholder="Your password..."
                   Margin="0"
                   Style="{StaticResource LoginFormEntry}"
                   Text="{Binding Password}"></Entry>

            <Button Text="Log in"
                    HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                    Margin="30, 30, 30,0"
                    Command="{Binding LoginButtonClickedCommand}"></Button>


        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView.Content>
</ScrollView>
```

**Styles:**

```
<Style TargetType="Label" x:Key="LoginFormLabel">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalTextAlignment" Value="Start"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Fill"></Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: You can add an Android Handler for Label (or use mapper) to change the native control padding/letter spacing: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/customize?view=net-maui-8.0#customize-a-control

Comment: Could you please show the code about ```LoginFormEntry``` style?

Comment: Actually, I cannot reproduce based on your code. That may relate to the style for the Entry control.